# Are the signal-slot execution in Qt parallelized?

Tags: multithreading, qt, signals-slots

I have a basic Qt question on the way it handles Signals and Slots. I am very new to the framework, so pardon me if it sounds stupid. I was wondering if I have certain signals connected to certain slots.

```
signal1() ---> slot1(){ cout <<"a"; }
signal2() ---> slot2(){ cout <<"b"; }
signal3() ---> slot3(){ cout <<"c"; }
```

And in my code I call

```
emit signal1();
emit signal2();
emit signal3();
```

Does Qt guarantee to print out "abc" to the screen, in other words process the slots sequentially? Or will it spawn a separate thread to execute each slot?
Thanks!

Comment: Qt does never spawn any additional threads unasked that one would have to mess with. Qt might use some additional threads internally (e.g. for I/O like QProcess and QNetworkAccessManager), but they are never exposed to the API user. A single-threaded program without any explicit multithreading has only one thread one has to care about.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By default:

1) If the signal is emitted in the thread which the receiving object has affinity then the slots connected to this signal are executed immediately, just like a normal function calls. Execution of the code following the `emit` statement will occur once all slots have returned.

2) Otherwise, the slot is invoked when control returns to the event loop of the receiver's thread. The code following the `emit` keyword will continue immediately, and the slots will be executed later in the receiver's thread.

More info about connection types here: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/threads-qobject.html#signals-and-slots-across-threads

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to Kotlomoy's correct answer :)

You can also control the type of connection from the default by supplying the optional parameter ConnectionType:
connect(obj, signal, obj, slot, connectionType)

Where your main options are:

- Qt::QueuedConnection: This will only run when control returns to the event loop of the thread. I.e. will be added to the queue. specify this if you don't want your slot to be processed immediately which can be very useful.
- Qt::DirectConnection: Alternatively you can specify direct connection (even between threads if you want), but generally you do not need or want to use this option since it is default when a signal is emitted to a slot within the same thread.

If you use QueuedConnection you grantee "abc" to be printed to the screen in that order.

Its worth noting if a directConnect event occurs while you are processing a previous slot (lets say some other external event triggers a signal like an IpSocket input) then you will get "interrupted". This won't happen in your simple example.